# why i cannot use the auto keyword in the last version of gcc

Tags: c++

All, recently i tried to use the new features supported by c++11, and i wrote such statement however the compiler ran failed.

```
auto x = 1;
```

the report error listed below:

```
D:\DEV\CBCppTest\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
D:\DEV\CBCppTest\main.cpp|22|warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]|
D:\DEV\CBCppTest\main.cpp|22|error: 'x' does not name a type|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

Why the last gcc version 4.7.0 on MinGW cannot support the this statement. But the compiler of vs10 passed. Could anyone know the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 33):

"GCC provides experimental support for the 2011 ISO C++ standard. This support can be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options; the former disables GNU extension."

It comes from here: [c+11 support](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html)

Answer (score 9):

To explain what the compiler is actually complaining about: `auto` used to be an old C keyword, declaring that this variable has *automatic storage*. These keywords have little to do with the type system, they specify how variable are represented in memory: where they're stored (processor register vs. main memory / stack) and how the memory is reclaimed. `auto` means the variable is stored on the stack (though the processor may optimise it into a processor register) and the memory is *automatically reclaimed* when the variable goes out of scope – which is the right choice in almost any situation<sup>1</sup> and thus the default, so virtually nobody ever used this old `auto` keyword. Yet `C++03` still provided backwards compatibility for code that has it; today's compilers still want to support legacy code.

---

<sup>1</sup>Though often you want *objects* to reside on the heap, you'll still be accessing those through variables on the stack; C++ has its own methods of using heap-allocated memory (`new`, `std::vector` etc.), you don't need the unsafe C-style `malloc` stuff.

Answer (score 8):

When compiling, you need to add `-std=c++11` to g++ command line.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the feature not being enable by default by the GCC compiler. If you're on Codeblocks, go to Settings --> Compiler and enable the feature as shown - https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Wq6.jpg

Answer (score 1):

For me adding "-std=c++0x"" to g++ command line fixed the issue.